# Unable to Call remote bash script from php

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to execute a remote bash script using the private IP address of that machine. It is in the same VLAN. However, I am getting a result of null is this the right way to call a remote bash script ?

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $result =shell_exec('sh http://10.xxx.77.xxx/script/helloworld.sh ');

    /* making json string with the result from shell script */
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    /* and we are done and exit */

?>
```

helloworld.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Output:

{"result":null}

Comment: cough cough shellshock

Comment: Do you realize that if it was possible then nothing would prevent you from invoking a bash script on google's server?

Comment: Is there an alternative to calling bash script in more secure way  ? For example to trigger cron job from php which in turn has the command to execute that shell script ?

Comment: or executing a java class file from php that has the commands to run the bash script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
exec('./path/to/bash', $result);
```

And if this is on another server, I highly doubt you'll be able to execute it. You would have to set a 777 permission (probably , which is a security risk, depending on the script. Also, if it IS on another server, why not just put it on the same server running the script?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into a library designed for this. **phpseclib** (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind for me. I've had a little experience using this library for key generation but it will allow you to create a simple SSH connection using any of the usual protocols and run commands through an SSH connection.

Check [this section](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html) of the documentation.